# Check follow status in aggregate mongo / mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have this schema for users where followers/followed is array and the reference the same schema

```
  var userSchema = new Schema({
  username: { type: String, unique: true, trim: true, required: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  followers: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "users" }],
  followed: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "users" }],
  registered: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  admin: { type: Number, default: 0 }
});
```

What I am looking for to return the follow status, if the _id is contains in followed array give me for example follow_status: 1

```
[
      {
        $match: { username: new RegExp(username, "i") }
      },
      {
        $unwind: "$followers"
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "users",
          localField: "followers",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "info"
        }
      },
      {
        $unwind: "$info"
      },
      {
        $project: {
          info: {
            _id: 1,
            username: 1,
            avatar: { $ifNull: ["$avatar", ""] },
            fullname: { $ifNull: ["$fullname", ""] }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$info" }
      },
      {
        $limit: 1000
      }
    ]
```

Current pipeliens result

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5a906653f52e66c9c7a23cb6",
        "username": "User1"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5a908eb564a726cf8ec7e0a3",
        "username": "User2"
    }
]
```

Comment: Use  `follow_status: {$cond:[{$in:["$_id", "$followed"]}, 1, 0]}` in `$project `in 3.4

Comment: always return 0

Comment: This works fine `$cond: [{ $in: ["$info._id", "$followed"] }, 1, 0]` Thanks a lot